# Dart: The argument type Iterable<dynamic>? can't be assigned to the parameter type Iterable<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

The class below is a stripped-down version of code generated at https://app.quicktype.io/ There are two lines like this:

```
genreIds: json["genre_ids"] == null ? null : List<int>.from(json["genre_ids"].map((x) => x)),
```

The initial error is `The method can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can't be 'null'`. That can be fixed by making the call conditional: `?.map`  .Making that change results in this error: `'The argument type Iterable<dynamic>? can't be assigned to the parameter type Iterable<dynamic>'`. I can't see how to fix the second error.

```
class MovieResult {
    MovieResult({
        this.genreIds,
    });
    final List<int>? genreIds;
    factory MovieResult.fromRawJson(String str) => MovieResult.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());
    factory MovieResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MovieResult(
        genreIds: json["genre_ids"] == null ? null : List<int>.from(json["genre_ids"].map((x) => x)),
    );
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "genre_ids": genreIds == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(genreIds.map((x) => x)),// *****ERROR*****
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `!` while you've already checked null

```
List<dynamic>.from(genreIds!.map((x) => x)),
```

Comment: Yes, I realise I could do that, but I try to avoid using ! wherever possible, in favor of having the compiler check null-safety at compile time.

Comment: Good choice, You have already done null case `genreIds == null ? null` and It is safe now

Answer (score 0):

Your genreIds can be null so the List returned in that case may also be null. Fix this by changing

```
List<dynamic> to List<dynamic>?
```

So toJson() method will become

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "genre_ids": genreIds == null ? null : List<dynamic>?.from(genreIds.map((x) => x)),
    };
```

Comment: I've already tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't work: "The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type' "